# What is the meaning of an Underscore in javascript function parameter?

Tags: javascript

I was going through the code of one of the chart library written in javascript, wherein I've seen passing underscore(`_`) as a function parameter. What does that mean?

```js
chart.x = function(_) {
  if (!arguments.length) return lines.x;
  lines.x(_);
  lines2.x(_);
  return chart;
};
```

Can someone please update on this...Thanks.

Comment: so @GabyakaG.Petrioli if you call that function with any parameter irrespective of type or no. of parameters..it will call that function?

Comment: In the specific function if you pass no parameters it will return `lines.x` right away, if you pass more than one, then it will use the first only and pass it to `lines.x` and `lines2.x` and finally return the `chart`.

Comment: Note that it [potentially has meaning in TypeScript](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/3442), specifically that it's a parameter in a function signature that's _not going to be used_. (That's a TSLint link, but it seems to have carried over. Haven't found a better "official" source yet.)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

The underscore symbol `_` is a valid identifier in JavaScript, and in your example, it is being used as a function parameter.

A single underscore is a convention used by some javascript programmers to indicate to other programmers that they should "ignore this binding/parameter". Since JavaScript doesn't do parameter-count checking the parameter could have been omitted entirely.

This symbol is often used (by convention again) in conjunction with fat-arrow functions to make them even terser and readable, like this:

```
const fun = _ => console.log('Hello, World!')
fun()
```

In this case, the function needs no params to run, so the developer has used the underscore as a convention to indicate this. The same thing could be written like this:

```
const fun = () => console.log('Hello, World!')
fun()
```

The difference is that the second version is a function with no parameters, but the first version has a parameter called _ that is ignored. These are different though and the second version is safer, if slightly more verbose (1 extra character).

Also, consider a case like

```
arr.forEach(function (_, i) {..})
```

Where `_` indicates the first parameter is not to be used.

The use of underscores like this can get very confusing when using the popular lodash or underscore libraries.

Comment: If it was omitted entirely, then he would have nothing to pass to `lines.x()` and `lines2.x(_)`.

Comment: To confirm my understanding, passing `_` in this case is equivalent to passing `null`, and `_` is used just for aesthetics/readability?

Comment: @MarkJackson The `_` will still hold a value. You can test this by declaring a function with a parameter `_` that logs that parameter, and you will see it logs whatever was passed in

Comment: @MarkJackson: No, `_` isn't special; it's a valid identifier in JS, just like `x` or `foo`. These definitions are equivalent: a) `function f(x) { return x; }`, b) `function f(_) { return _; }`. I'd say @sagar43's answer is incorrect, because `_` _is_ in fact used in the body of `chart.x`, so omitting the parameter (`chart.x = function() { ... }`) would change the function's semantics.

Comment: @SimonAlling I've edited the answer to address your concerns.

Comment: @sagar43 Could you please elaborate on how "the second version is safer"?

Comment: In your case `arr.forEach(function (_, i) {..})`, what should I use for the second parameter if I want to get only the third parameter...? 

Answer (score 20):

_ in fat arrow function is called as **throwaway variable**. It means that actually we're creating an variable but simply ignoring it.
More devs are now a days using this as syntactic sugar or short hand while writing code, as it's easy and one character less to write the code.

> Instead of using _, you can use other variables like temp, x, etc

for examples:

```
() => console.log('Hello World')



_ => console.log('Hello World')




x => console.log('Hello World')
```

But personally i prefer to use () type over throwaway variable if no arguments are needed.

See the following code, then you will understand it better.

_ as an argument,

```
  f = _=> {
    return _ + 2 ;
}
```

> f(3) will return 5

[For better understanding, check wes bos](https://wesbos.com/arrow-functions/)