# How would I know if "err" argument is needed in the callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, callback, mongodb-nodejs-driver

I am a beginner in mongodb and javascript.

I have here a code for simple **find** method in Mongodb Nodejs.
This code does not work.

The solution is to change the last line to this: `cursor.limit(10).toArray((err, docs) => console.log(docs));`.

What I do not understand is why do I need to include the `err` argument here? Here is the [documentation for toArray method](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/classes/FindCursor.html#toArray). It does not say here that `err` parameter is needed. How would I know that `err` argument is needed here or in other methods?

Thank you very much! I think this is a very basic concept and I will appreciate any input.

```js
const client = new MongoClient(uri);
client.connect()
.then(() => {
  const db = client.db('sample_mflix');
  const coll = db.collection('movies');

  const cursor = coll.find();
  cursor.limit(10).toArray((docs) => console.log(docs));

})
```

Comment: "*It does not say here that err parameter is needed.*" the documentation states that you have to pass [`Callback`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/modules.html#Callback).

Comment: you should always have the error argument, not only when there are errors.

Comment: You have to check either the docs or the source to know what arguments will be passed to the callback.  Declaring the wrong arguments will still run in plain Javascript (not in TypeScript), but you will either be missing arguments to the callback or things will be passed in the wrong argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation you linked, we can see that [`FindCursor.toArray`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/classes/FindCursor.html#toArray) has two valid syntax permutations:

1. `toArray(): Promise<TSchema[]>`
2. `toArray(callback: Callback<TSchema[]>): void`

Since you are using the second, we need to look at the [documentation for `Callback`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/modules.html#Callback). It says there is only one valid syntax:

1. `Callback<T>: (error?: AnyError, result?: T) => void`

You must include the `error` parameter to have a valid `Callback`, then, and you must have a valid `Callback` to use the `toArray(:Callback)` permutation.

---

The typical way to convey that you don't care about the value of a parameter [is to use an underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637013/what-is-the-meaning-of-an-underscore-in-javascript-function-parameter) (`_`) as the parameter name.

```
const client = new MongoClient(uri);
client.connect()
    .then(() => {
        const db = client.db('sample_mflix');
        const coll = db.collection('movies');

        const cursor = coll.find();
        cursor.limit(10).toArray((_, docs) => { console.log(docs); });
})
```

---

If you wanted to use the first permutation (which returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)), it would look like the following. This is how you're already handling `MongoClient.connect`.

```
const client = new MongoClient(uri);
client.connect()
    .then(() => {
        const db = client.db('sample_mflix');
        const coll = db.collection('movies');

        const cursor = coll.find();
        cursor.limit(10).toArray()
            .then(docs => { console.log(docs); });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

actually the docs say's to pass a callback.have you checked what arrguments that callback take?? yes , it's error and result.

```
toArray(callback: Callback<TSchema[]>): void
Callback<T>: (error?: AnyError, result?: T) => void
```