# React Material OnInputChange, remove unneeded variables

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using React Material OnInputChange on Autocomplete. How do I get rid of event and reason, below when not needed? Just trying to remove extra variables from Material UI. See greyed out variables in VSCode Eslint.

Resource: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/

```
onInputChange={async (
  event: object,
  value: string,
  reason: string,
) => {
  setProcedureCodeLength(value.length);
  if (value.length >= 3) {
    const codes = await getProcedureCodes(
      value,
      undefined,
    );
    setProcedureCodeOptions(codes);
  } else {
    setProcedureCodeOptions([]);
  }
}}
```

[image]

> 'event', 'reason' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)

Comment: ok, so If I only have an event variable,  I can get rid of value variable? How about last variable reason, should I just delete that? thanks cc @dippas

Comment: sorry my bad, thats just a warning, you can safely, replace `event` by `_`

Comment: hi @dippas not sure I fully get it, started learning react few weeks ago, can you write as answer in code, and I can send points? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to stop that warning, you have to change this `event: object` to `_`,  no need to set type because it will infer its type to `React.SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>`

For `reason: string`, just deleted it

It stays like this:

```
onInputChange={async (_, value: string) => {
```

See: [What is the meaning of an Underscore in javascript function parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637013/what-is-the-meaning-of-an-underscore-in-javascript-function-parameter)

Comment: if I don't need 'reason', I will also replace it with _,  thanks

Comment: actually doing two _ gives me an error, so should I just delete that last reason parameter? thanks